# The ‘from’ Keyword is not supported in this version of language

Tags: powershell, docker, windows-server-2016

While i am running following command in powershell in windows server 2016 :

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore RUN dism /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:iis-webserver /NoRestart
```

I am getting:

> The ‘from’ Keyword is not supported in this version of language”
>   error.

Please help me in getting this issue solved.

**[EDIT]**

Actually, I was wrong running FROM keyword in PowerShell. This will be dockerfile. Also when copy above from command in docker file and run:

```
 *docker build -t windowsserveriis .*
```

then I am getting:

> ltsc2019: Pulling from windows/servercore no matching manifest for
>   windows/amd64 10.0.14393 in the manifest list entries error.

Comment: why do you expect a non-powershell command to work in powershell? where is that command supposed to work?

Comment: actually i was following 

https://fluentbytes.com/deploying-asp-net-4-5-to-docker-on-windows/#comment-596988

 and 

https://www.wintellect.com/migrating-legacy-asp-net-apps-to-docker/ .

I already pulled docker window server image by docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2016 .

But then using FROM microsoft/windowsservercore RUN dism /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:iis-webserver /NoRestart ,i am getting above error.

Comment: so ... having read that article ... WHY do you expect it to have anything to do with **_powershell_**? this is NOT a powershell problem.

Answer (score 1):

The very same post is posted in the docker forum.

Those lines are valid declarations in a Dockerfile.

You might want to read about how to write a Dockerfile and build docker images:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

It is the official documentation and generaly valid regardless whether you want to build a Linux or Windows based Docker image.

Maybee this one is more friendly for Windows user:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/manage-windows-dockerfile

Though, I just took a peek at it. I highly recommend the first link, as ressources outside the official Docker dokumentation sometimes suggest odd approaches ;)

Comment: yes,i have posted that post in docker forum.
actually i was following 

https://fluentbytes.com/deploying-asp-net-4-5-to-docker-on-windows/#comment-596988

 and 

https://www.wintellect.com/migrating-legacy-asp-net-apps-to-docker/ .

I already pulled docker window server image by docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2016 .

But then using FROM microsoft/windowsservercore RUN dism /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:iis-webserver /NoRestart ,i am getting above error.

Comment: Let me quote a line from the first link, straight above the command you tried to execute in Powershell: "I prefer the later and for this we create a dockerfile that contains the following statements:". Like i already wrote: make yourself aquainted with how to write a Dockerfile and how to build images.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft Docs on Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_keywords?view=powershell-6), there is currently no version of PowerShell that supports the `From` keyword; it is currently ‘reserved for future use’. If you have contradictory information *from Microsoft*, please provide references, and include the output of `$psversiontable` in support of your assertion.

Comment: Please look into this following link :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/deployment/docker-aspnetmvc

Under,build the Image title you can see use of FROM keyword.

Comment: While I am not familiar with how Docker works, I see nothing there that says that the scripting material is a PowerShell script. By implication from the URI you provided, I would think that it's an ASP.NET script, which is more closely related to Visual BASIC and/or VBScript than to PowerShell.